# Unable to Script Table with SSMS version 18.4 on Azure SQL Serverless Pool

Tags: ssms, azure-synapse

I am trying to script a table using SSMS version 18.4 on Azure SQL Serverless Pool as follows:

[image]

However, I keep on gettinge the following error
[image]

The full error message is as follows:

> Invalid version: 16. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> ------------------------------ For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=15.0.18206.0+((SSMS_Rel).191029-2112)&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptingOptions.ConvertToSqlServerVersion(Int32
> majorVersion, Int32 minorVersion)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptingOptions.ConvertToSqlServerVersion(ServerVersion
> serverVersion)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UserSettings.ScriptingOptions.GetSmoScriptingOptions(SqlSmoObject
> smoObj)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ScriptNodeActionContext.Script(SqlTextWriter
> writer)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.SqlScriptMenu.OnScriptItemClick(Object
> sender, EventArgs e)

Can someone let me know if I need to downgrade my SSMS version?

Comment: Have you tried *updating* your version first? 18.4 is quite an old version. If that error is referring to "Version 16" of SQL Server, that means SQL Server 2022; you want SSMS 19 for that. Even for SSMS 18, the latest release is 18.12.1 (if I recall correctly).

Comment: I will try updating the version to 18.12.1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created synapse serverless pool and created external table.
Image for refence:

[image]

I connected to SSMS using required details.
Image for reference:

[image]

It connected successfully.
[image]

I try to create script for the external table in 18.0 version I got the error.
I tried in 18.12.1 version, it worked fine.
Image for reference:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Try It in 18.12.1 version. It is working fine.